# How to play wav file from directory path

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play wav file from my directory path which I saved in there before, but I can't play, I hope someone can help me

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
directoryPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",directoryPath,@"path1.wav",nil];
audioPath1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:directoryPath] error:NULL]; 
[audioPath1 play];
```

Comment: check that `audioPath1 != nil` (I'm betting it is) and use the `error:` parameter from `initWithContentsOfURL:` (don't set it to `NULL`).

Comment: @Inder thanks for reply, directory path is full,there is such a file as path1.wav, so i changed it and dont set it to NULL as you say now but still same problem.

Comment: @yucelbayram I have updated my answer please run that code and show us the output logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    audioPath1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:directoryPath] error:&error];
    if (!error) {
        [audioPath1 play];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in creating audio player:%@",[error description]);
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"File doesn't exists");
}
```

Use the above code and show us the console logs

Comment: thanks for quick reply , i already checked that with similar codes and there is such file but i understood problem, problem is my wav file isnt playable with quick player or any iphone's media player. But if it would be playable file than your code would work perfectly coz of that i mark it as an answer for it can help to other people.

Comment: AudioSessionInitialize(nil, nil, nil, nil);
    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
    UInt32 se = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(se), &se);

without this code my wav file doesn't play. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Should be Something like that,

```
-(void)playFileAdv:(NSString *)audioFile WithVolume:(float)audioLevelIndex{
    [self stopAlert];

    pSound = [[NSSound alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:audioFile byReference:NO];
    playRecursively = NO;
    [pSound setVolume:audioLevelIndex];
    [pSound setDelegate:self];
    [pSound play];

}
```